# Displaying SQL results in Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF application I'm working on that displays SQL query results in a DataGrid. So far I am getting a blank grid. My code is as follows:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="990" Margin="0,0,0,1">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
</DataGrid>
```

And this is the code for the grid

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillDataGrid();
    }

    private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT BatchNo, FormulaId, Description, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), SchStartDate, 101) SchStartDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), SchCompletionDate, 101) SchCompletionDate, BatchStatus, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), ActStartDate, 101) ActStartDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), ActCompletionDate, 101) ActCompletionDate, ProcessCellId, Notes FROM mf1.dbo.BM_View_SL_ProdBatches WHERE BatchStatus != 'Closed' AND SchCompletionDate < convert(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 101) AND BatchStatus != 'X' ORDER BY SchStartDate";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that you have a `DataGrid` inside a `DataGrid`, there's really nothing wrong with your code, as long as your query is returning data.

Comment: Could you tell me where I'm duplicating?

Comment: In your XAML......

Comment: Take a look at my sample. Obviously i used a different data table.

Comment: Thanks, I know it was something stupid like that.

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us...:O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XAML` should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication375.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication375"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
</Grid>
```

[image]